# Adding map image to intel xdk geolocation-co-ordinates already showing up

Tags: html, css, dictionary, geolocation, intel-xdk

I am trying to add an image of the app for geolocation co-ordinates to my app on the Intel XDK program. I have already obtained the co-ordinates for latitude and longitude which show up correctly. The map on the side of the screen however, needs to be dragged to update the location co-ordinates. Currently, the geolocation is accessed by pressing a button which implements the onclick listener.

Is there anyway to get an image to appear updated from google maps or to get a map to update dynamically so that it shows my actual co-ordinates rather than the town I select on the sidemap. For example, if I was in New York, I would need to drag the side map to New York to get those co-ordinates. If I were to go to Boston, the co-ordinates would still appear as New York unless I drag it to Boston. Is there anyway to get this to update as I leave for somewhere else and access the emulator in another city? Below is my code as it is so far with the co-ordinates appearing on the blank white screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>p
<!--HTML5 doctype-->

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="intelxdk.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var isIntel=window.intel&&window.intel.xdk
    // This event handler is fired once the intel libraries are ready
    function onDeviceReady() {
        //hide splash screen now that our app is ready to run
        intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.ui.launch();
        }, 50);
    }
    //initial event handler to detect when intel is ready to roll
    document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready", onDeviceReady, false);
</script>
<script src="js/appframework.ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    if(isIntel)
        $.ui.autoLaunch = false;
    $.ui.useOSThemes = true; //Change this to false to force a device theme
    $.ui.blockPageScroll();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($.ui.useOSThemes && (!$.os.ios||$.os.ios7))
            $("#afui").removeClass("ios");
    });
</script>
<link href="css/icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/af.ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script>
    function get_location() {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_map);
            }
        function show_map(position) {
  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

            document.write("latitude :" + latitude + "<br>");
            document.write("longitude :" + longitude + "<br>");
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="afui" class="ios">
    <div id="header" class="header"></div>
    <div id="content" style="">
        <div class="panel" title="Main" data-nav="nav_0" id="main" selected="selected"
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgb(128, 191, 255);"
        data-appbuilder-object="page" data-header="header_0" data-footer="default_footer">


            <div class="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative;" data-appbuilder-object="container">
                <img src="images/intel.jpg" style="width: 100%;" alt="Title" data-appbuilder-object="image"
                class="" title="Main Screen">
                <div class="text_item" data-appbuilder-object="text" style="text-align: center;">Welcome to the Tutorials App.
                    <br>Please select an option.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" title="About" data-nav="nav_0" id="page_1" data-appbuilder-object="page"
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgb(128, 191, 255);"
        data-header="header_0" data-footer="default_footer">
            <div class="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" data-appbuilder-object="container">
                <img src="images/intel.jpg" style="width: auto; height: 40%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"
                alt="Title" data-appbuilder-object="image" class="" title="About">
                <div class="text_item" data-appbuilder-object="text" style="text-align: center;">The about screen
                    <br>about
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" title="Tutorials" data-nav="nav_0" id="page_2" data-appbuilder-object="page"
        style="" data-header="header_0" data-footer="default_footer">
            <ul class="list" data-appbuilder-object="list" style="">
                <li><a href="#page_3">HTML Tutorial</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#page_4">CSS Tutorial</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#page_5">Geolocation</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" title="HTML Tutorial" id="page_3" data-appbuilder-object="page"
        style="">
            <div class="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative;" data-appbuilder-object="container">
                <img src="images/intel.jpg" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 100px;" alt="Title"
                data-appbuilder-object="image" class="" title="intel">
                <div class="text_item" data-appbuilder-object="text" style="text-align: center;">Use HTML like this.
                    <iframe width="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9gTw2EDkaDQ" frameborder="0"
                    allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" title="CSS Tutorial" data-nav="nav_0" id="page_4" data-appbuilder-object="page"
        style="width: 100%;" data-header="header_0" data-footer="footer_2">
            <div class="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative;" data-appbuilder-object="container">
                <img src="images/intel.jpg" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 100px;" alt="Title"
                data-appbuilder-object="image" class="" title="intel1">
                <div class="text_item" data-appbuilder-object="text" style="text-align: center;">Use CSS like this</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" title="Geolocation" data-nav="nav_0" id="page_5" data-appbuilder-object="page"
        style="width: 100%;" data-header="header_0" data-footer="footer_3">
            <div class="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" data-appbuilder-object="container">
                <img src="images/intel.jpg" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 100px;" alt="Title"
                data-appbuilder-object="image" class="" title="intel2">
                <div class="text_item" data-appbuilder-object="text" style="text-align: center;">Find Geolocation here</div>
                <a class="button" href="#page_8" style="width: 100%; position: relative; z-index: 2;"
                data-appbuilder-object="button" data-transition="slide" id="button_8"
                onclick="get_location();">Geolocation</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" title="Display Location" data-nav="nav_0" id="page_7" data-appbuilder-object="page"
        style="" data-footer="default_footer" data-header="header_0">

            <div>

                <title style="">Geolocation</title>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" style="">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"
                style="">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
                style=""></script>
                <script src="intelxdk.js" style=""></script>
                <script src="cordova.js" style=""></script>
                <script src="xhr.js" style=""></script>

                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" style=""></script>

                <style type="text/css" style="">
                    * { -webkit-user-select:none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); -ms-touch-action:none;}
                </style>




                <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
                    <h1>Determining Your Location</h1>
                </div>
                </body>
            </div>




        </div>

        <footer><a href="#main" class="icon home" style="">Home</a><a href="#page_1" class="icon info"
            style="">About</a><a href="#page_2" class="icon star" style="">Tutorials</a>
            <a href="#page_7" class="icon key" style="">Resources</a>
        </footer>
        <div class="panel" title="New Page" data-nav="nav_0" id="page_7" data-appbuilder-object="page"
        style=""></div>
        <div class="panel" title="New Page" data-nav="nav_0" id="page_8" data-appbuilder-object="page"
        style=""></div>
        <div class="panel" title="New Page" data-nav="nav_0" id="page_9" data-appbuilder-object="page"
        style=""></div>
        <div class="panel" title="New Page" data-nav="nav_0" id="page_10" data-appbuilder-object="page"
        style=""></div>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="footer"> <a class="icon home">Home</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="navbar" class="footer"> <a class="icon home">Home</a>
</div>
<header id="header_0" data-appbuilder-object="header">
    <h1 class="apptitle"> Tutorials App</h1>
</header>
<nav id="nav_0" data-appbuilder-object="nav">
    <h1>Side Menu</h1>
</nav>
<footer id="footer_1" data-appbuilder-object="footer"><a href="#page_1" class="icon left">Previous</a><a href="#main" class="icon home">Home</a>
    <a href="#page_4" class="icon right">Next</a>
</footer>
<footer id="footer_2" data-appbuilder-object="footer"><a href="#page_3" class="icon left">Previous</a><a href="#main" class="icon home">Home</a>
    <a href="#page_5" class="icon right">Next</a>
</footer>
<footer id="footer_3" data-appbuilder-object="footer"><a href="#page_4" class="icon left">Previous</a><a href="#main" class="icon home">Home</a>
    <a href="#page_7" class="icon right">Next</a>
</footer>
<footer id="default_footer" data-appbuilder-object="footer"><a href="#main" class="icon home">Home</a><a href="#page_1" class="icon info">About</a>
    <a href="#page_2" class="icon star">Tutorials</a><a href="#page_7" class="icon key">Resources</a>
</footer>





</html>
```

END EDIT *****************************************************************************

I removed the two html tags before pasting and saving. The above is the edited code where I was trying to get the satellite and the map to show up. I am still only getting the co-ordinates to show up on the white screen. Currently I have a button which links from the geolocation page, id= page_5 to the display location page, id=page_7. the co-ordinates are showing up on that page, but still no sign of the map/satellite image. Is there anyway to get them to appear either both on one page, or on two separate pages which I can link?

When I look at the design page I can see "determining your location" but this does not show up within the emulator.

Comment: The emulator is essentially running in a webview on your host machine (laptop, &c) so some technical details will not match running on the phone, it's more to get a rough idea of the layout and do basic debugging.  What do you mean when you say the Nokia "only shows lattitude"?  Do you mean the geo api returns undefined for longitude?

Comment: yes it will give the latitude co-ordinates on the white screen and the longitude doesn't appear, as if i had never added it. it's only necessary to get it working on the emulator anyway. have you any idea how to get a dynamic map to appear on the screen instead of white?

Comment: I'll try your posted code and see what I can figure out.

Comment: Have you tried the "Geolocation Demo"?  You can open a new project, choose "Work with a Demo" and select it.  I think it does what you're trying to do and it works for me in the emulator and on my phone.

Comment: yes it has worked on a sample project on the emulator, though it takes a while longer to load. does yours update on your phone dynamically, like if you go to a different area of town for example? I can get it to update co-ordinates but only when I use the mouse to plot somewhere else on the map. Would it pick up satellites at all? Do settings need to be change on my phone(HTC one) or my computer even(Windows 7)?

Comment: On my phone, it seems to zoom out far enough to include all way points when I change locations far enough away.

Comment: so it is doing it by itself without you needing press anything like a mouse when you move?

Comment: Yes, it automatically zoomed out.

Comment: ah yes I see it does work. Would you know how to incorporate the code from that demo into my code now so that it shows both the location co-ordinates and the map on different pages? Any time I add the code to mine it does not save. I want to have it so the user will select the geolocation tab, then press the button which shows co-ordinates, then the next page to show the map. then press left/right arrows or home icon to return. Would you know how to incorporate it into the existing code? Even when I choose save it is as if I have done nothing.

Comment: Do you mean you copy/paste code into the XDK editor, and it doesn't save it?  That should work.  You could also edit outside of the XDK (preferably with XDK shut down or not on that project), then open it in the XDK.

Comment: Yes it didn't save it. What do you mean by edit it outside of the SDK and then open it? Do you mean in something like NotePad++ for example? Or did you mean something different? I managed to get the screen as you said and want to be add navigation to it so that one screen will have the button, the next will have the map and the next will have the co-ordinates. Is it possible to put navigation arrows or a footer on top of the map?

Comment: Yes, use NotePad, or whatever editor you prefer.  Safest thing to do is quit XDK, edit, then restart XDK, though it's supposed to recognize when the file changes outside the XDK.  Don't know about arrows.

Comment: whenever I paste the code from the demo into my xdk code, I have done it underneath where I have the variables for the latitude and longitude but whenever I paste it, it makes the co-ordinates disappear and the map doesn't show up. how much of it would I need to edit? Or would you know where to paste it? I have checked on Intel itself but it seems vague-ideally I want to either have the co-ordinates and satellite/map view on one page or to have the option to press a button on the map page to take you to those co-ordinates. I have edited my code to show the intel demo code if you can help.